# SSHFS between two firewalled machines via third-party proxy

Tags: proxy, firewall, nat, sshfs

Both my home machine and my destination machine are behind NAT routers I have zero control over.  I have a non-firewalled VPS that I can use for proxying requests.

How do I set up sshfs from my home machine to my destination machine?

To complicate matters a little, my home machine is windows and my destination machine is OS X.

Comment: Are you trying to connect _from_ or _to_ Windows? What SSH software are you using on the Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can do some nasty ssh port forwarding hacks using the -R option. The one hosting sshfs conencts to your vm using

> ssh  -R2222:localhost:22

then to your server from the consumer with

> ssh  -L22:locahost:2222

then mount sshfs using localhost as the remote server address